# Código não reconhece imagem da pasta xhdpi

Tags: android, android-studio, imagem, drawable

Salvei algumas imagens diretamente na pasta drawable. Estas, o Android Studio reconhece normalmente. Mas as imagens salvas nas pastas mdli, hdpi, xhdpi, xxhdpi e xxxhdpi o código não reconhece e dá erro. Alguém sabe dizer o q pode estar acontecendo?
Valeu!

Comment: Qual erro esta dando?

Comment: Os arquivos que estão nas pastas dpi, xhdpi, etc, não aparecem na lista das opções quando eu digito R.drawable

Comment: e se eu digito R.drawable.image o código fica vermelho, como se não existisse o arquivo

Comment: Como você adicionou essas imagens?

Comment: Salvei diretamente pelo Finder (Mac)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/29294287/6809703

Comment: @TotallyUncool Agora sim! muuuuito obrigado. Virei a noite tentando entender isso. Agora vou tentar dormir. hehe